# XPUB export from MultiBit HD wallet

Tags: multibit, private-key-export

Is there a way to to export/copy wallet's XPUB from MultiBit HD wallet (windows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in the UI no.

You can work out the XPUB from your wallet words by making an **offline** copy of https://dcpos.github.io/bip39/ and then using that.

If it is a regular MultBit HD wallet it is the BIP 32 panel you want.

Use it offline for security of your wallet words obviously.

Comment: If I load the xpub onto Mycelium app and ask somebody to send me a payment to a derivated address, that money can be spent later from MultiBit-HD, right?